# Entity Framework Group by based on a Nullable Primary Key column

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

My entity for storing address looks like below and referring to multiple tables as foreign key like country continent etc

```
public class ContactAddress
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Contact))]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    public virtual  Contact Contact { get; set; } 
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Continent))]
    public int? ContinentId { get; set; }

    public virtual  Continent Continent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Country))]
    public int? CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual  Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Trying to fetch the count of address values country-wise and continent-wise and map the result to a `List<GeoStatsModel>` which is like

```
public class GeoStatsModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Country Id
    public string Name { get; set; }  //Country Name
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Managed to generate the query like below

```
 List<GeoStatsModel> response = new List<GeoStatsModel>();

 response = context.ContactAddresses
                   .Where(a => a.IsPrimary == true && contactIds.Contains(a.ContactId))
                   .GroupBy(a => a.CountryId) 
                   .Select(g => new GeoStatsModel 
                                    {
                                        Id = (int)g.Key, 
                                        Name = (g.First().Country!=null)? g.First().Country.Name: "",
                                        Count = g.Count() 
                                    }).ToList();
```

At the time of execution, I get the error:

> The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector:
> (Nullable)c.CountryId,  ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: ContactAddress
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
>
> .Select(s => s.Country)   .First()' could not be translated. Either
> rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to
> client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

How can we correctly return the name from foreign key table and group the results?

Comment: EF Core 6 can translate this query. Update question with correct tag and version.

Comment: I had a similar problem last week and everything I read, suggested that GroupBy is basically broken in EF Core 6.  We ended up doing the grouping in memory.

Comment: In this case you can easily fix it by adding Country.Name to the GroupBy which turns it into the supported *key + aggregate* query shape.

Comment: @GertArnold Can you provide an example / link if possible?

Comment: Too much for a comment, see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GroupBy` support is limited in EF core. It basically supports statements that are supported by SQL, in EF core 6 a bit more.

In SQL it's not possible to group by `CountryId` and have the country's name in the result set too (at least not in all RDBMS's). To do it in SQL, the statement should join with `Country` and then group by `CountryId` and `Country.Name`. That's what EF also supports:

```cs
var response = context.ContactAddresses
    .Where(a => a.IsPrimary && contactIds.Contains(a.ContactId))
    .GroupBy(a => new { a.CountryId, a.Country.Name }) 
    .Select(g => new GeoStatsModel 
    {
        Id = g.Key.CountryId ?? 0, 
        Name = g.Key.Name ?? string.Empty,
        Count = g.Count() 
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: This seems to be getting broken in some scenarios where there is NO Value for Coutry Id , [ CountryId is a NUllable column] and the error message getting is
 Nullable object must have a value.

Comment: managed to sort it out this way as well
.GroupBy(a => new { CountryId = a.Country == null ? -1  : a.CountryId , a.Country.Name }) 
But not sure which one is a good approach

Comment: I reverted my revision because I already converted a null `CountryId` to 0. I don't really understand how you could get this error.